# Unable to to intercept Spring @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-async

I have a public method annotated with `@Async`. This method is not in the controller. I want to intercept the thread after completion of the thread execution so that I can clear certain ThreadLocals.

I already looked into `AsyncHandlerInterceptor` but this gets hit when the controller receives the request and not before and after the `@Async` execution.

```
public class SampleAsyncHandlerInterceptor implements AsyncHandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterConcurrentHandlingStarted " + request.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("preHandle " + request.getRequestURI());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("postHandle " + request.getRequestURI());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterCompletion " + request.getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

What I would like is an interceptor like CallableProcessingInterceptor, but for `@Async` operation.

Comment: @NathanHughes I use it to hold some contextual data to be used later instead of passing the information all the way from controller to underlying class as formal parameters. I could of course clear the threadlocal in a finally block in the run method of the runnable, but i'm looking for an alternative interceptor. I need to clear this just to be safe. I expect the value to be over-written on every request.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncHandlerInterceptor` is for web requests, `@Async` is general annotation which allows to delegate method execution to thread pool. No surprise these do not work well **together**.

`@Async` allows to provide name of thread pool. You can create your own pool which wraps all submitted tasks into your class so later you will intercept all operation with task.